# finishCondition based on feature being drawn

Tags: openlayers, draw-interaction

I have a [`draw interaction`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Draw.html) in Openlayers 4.

I'm using it to draw polygons. I would like to **continue drawing** the polygon if its area is less than a default value.

I tried using the property `finishCondition`, but it takes an `ol.MapBrowserEvent` and feature is not accesible.

```
finishCondition(event) { /* return (true or false) based on feature */ }
```

It seems that the event is fired before feature is added to the source so I can't take the feature from the source.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution:

I created a variable whichs points to the feature being drawn:

```
new ol.interaction.Draw({
      ...,
      stopClick: true,
      finishCondition: (event) => {
        const area = ol.Sphere.getArea(geomDrawn)
        const [minArea, maxArea] = [20*20, 1500*1500]
        return area > minArea && area < maxArea
      }
 })
```

And getting the geom from feature `change` event:

```
onDrawStart(event) {

  const { feature } = event

  this.listenerDraw = feature.getGeometry().on('change', event => {
    const geom = event.target        
    geomDrawn = geom
    ...
  }
}
```